# linking sfml with cmake (Windows MinGW)

Tags: cmake, linker, sfml

I can't seem to link `SFML` to my executable using `cmake`.

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(Tut3)

set(LIBS_DIR ~/../../Libraries)

add_executable(Tut3 main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${LIBS_DIR}/sfml/cmake/Modules)
find_package(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics)
target_link_libraries(Tut3 ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

**Error I get when running cmake:**

> CMake Error at C:/Libraries/sfml/cmake/Modules/FindSFML.cmake:355
>   (message):  Could NOT find SFML (missing: SFML_SYSTEM_LIBRARY
>   SFML_WINDOW_LIBRARY  SFML_GRAPHICS_LIBRARY)
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)

the sfml directory contains a 32bit `MinGW` compiled `sfml` repository. I am using Windows. The cmake command I use is:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..dir..
```

Comment: You should compile SFML first, and then point CMake to SFML's **install** directory, not its source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module to look for SFML won't look relative to its own position. Instead, it will try a few common paths (non-Windows systems) in addition to a few specific variables to try and find the actual library.

To solve this, you should do two things:

- Move the `FindSFML.cmake` script to a sub directory of your own project, e.g. `cmake/FindSFML.cmake` and adjust the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` value accordingly.
- Add a new CMake variable `SFML_ROOT` pointing to the directory where you installed SFML (in your case `C:/Libraries/sfml`). This shouldn't be hardcoded in the `CMakeLists.txt` file and instead be passed once when invoking CMake (i.e. `cmake -DSFML_ROOT=C:/...`; this is saved in the cache).

Also there are a few problems with the structure of your `CMakeLists.txt`. You should use this instead:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(Tut3)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake) # Tell CMake where to find the module
find_package(SFML REQUIRED COMPONENTS graphics window system) # Look for SFML

include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR}) # You forgot this line above; add SFML's include dir
add_executable(Tut3 main.cpp) # Define the target

target_link_libraries(Tut3 ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES}) # Link SFML and dependencies
```

Comment: Your answer worked (or at least it made cmake find the libraries... I still got some liker error that I have to figure out) but is the procedure you describe applicable to all FindXXX scripts, or is the "SFML_ROOT variable method" specific to sfml?

Comment: It's specific. As an alternative, install SFML to `<current drive>/usr` and the mentioned Linux paths should kick in.