# SFML with Qt and Cmake

Tags: qt, cmake, sfml

How can I add the SFML library to my Qt project using CMake and CMakeLists?

**Here is my folder structure:**

[image]

**Inside "External libraries" is where I have extracted my SFML zip:**

[image]

Comment: There are several questions on Stack Overflow about using SFML library with CMake. Have you checked them? E.g. [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671299/linking-sfml-with-cmake-windows-mingw).

Comment: I tried to apply the approach suggested. However, I keep getting an error that says "No such file as "FindSFML.cmake" can be found". I inspected the folders and indeed there is no file called "FindSFML.cmake". There is a file called "SFMLConfig.cmake".

Comment: If your SFML installation has `SFMLConfig.cmake` file, then see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71900677/cmake-project-building-with-sfml-library).